# Active(Debug) option missing in Configuration drop down Vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I was following instructions for preparing my app to go through a Profiler. The instruction states that I should choose Active(Debug) in the configuration dropdown. However the only options I see are Active(Release),Debug,Release and All configurations. Any suggestions on why Active(Debug) is not showing up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Active` is for the mode you are currently using.

Comment: So how do I change it to Active(Debug)